# GPL 2 Theme using a framework for commercial Theme?

Tags: themes

I'm new to WordPress and I have a question about license.

Can I use a GPL 2 Theme (downloaded from http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/) as a framework for Commercial Theme?

I searched and I found that Yes as long I keep the same License, but what are the changes I can make?

Can I modify the Author.... Name ... from style.css?
What are the credits I have to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:

You may change everything as long as you keep the same license.

No credit is actually required.

But it is polite. I would add it in the stylesheet under the notes section with a link back to the original.

---

Provide the original author and link to the source.

Something like "Based on the original work of John Doe: http://www.johndoe.com/myawesomecode"

Comment: Only the link back? or other like credit to, forked... correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks

Comment: You can modify the code in any way you want, and you can distribute it, even commercially, provided that you retain the original *license*. You are not required to retain any sort of public-facing link. As for copyright attribution: you absolutely need to **retain the original copyright notice**. The usual location for this attribution is in the **style.css header docblock**. Indicate your own copyright attribution and license, and then note that the work is derived from another work, and retain (or add) the original work's copyright attribution and license.

Comment: ^ What he said.